# How to remove old iOS device backup (mobile backup) files in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, backup, catalina

Before migrating to macOS Catalina, if I had old iOS device backups, I was able to remove them via the Preference window of the iTunes app. Now, the iTunes app is gone.

The backup files still reside in `~/Library/Application Support/MoibleSync` and are eating up a huge amount of disk space (200GB+ in my case, since I have multiple devices).

In macOS Catalina, where can I access the UI which allows me to see available device backups, so that I can safely and selectively remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to delete old backups in Catalina, it's just in a really weird area. From the  menu go to "About This Mac", then to the "Storage" tab, click on the "Manage ..." button and then click on the "iOS Files" item in the sidebar. (Credit to this site https://www.howtogeek.com/665890/how-to-delete-iphone-and-ipad-backups-on-a-mac/. They also have nice step by step pictures too.)

Comment: This looks weird but it looks like a reasonable way to do. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with macOS Catalina, iOS device sync support has been moved from iTunes into the Finder app. iTunes app itself has been [discontinued](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT210200), and the iTunes media library now made available in standalone Apple Music, Apple TV, Apple Books, and Apple Podcasts.

This Apple Support document lists the steps to access the iOS device backups on macOS Catalina:

- [Locate backups of your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch - Find backups stored on your Mac or PC](https://support.apple.com/HT204215#findiTunes):

> To find a specific backup:
>
> 1. On a Mac with macOS Catalina 10.15 or later, open the Finder. On a Mac with macOS Mojave 10.14 or earlier, or on a PC, open iTunes. Click your device.
> 2. In Finder, under the General tab, click Manage Backups to see a list of your backups. From here, you can right-click on the backup that you want, then choose Show in Finder, or you can select Delete or Archive. In iTunes, choose Preferences, then click Devices. From here, you can right-click on the backup that you want, then choose Show in Finder, or you can select Delete or Archive.
>
> [image]

Once located, you can delete a backup file like you normally delete any file in Finder.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it will be available only if I plug the device. that was a trick. I usually don't sync with iTunes lately. There were old backups during 2015-2018 which synced from old devices I'm not using anymore.

Comment: Yes, iOS integration with the Mac generally requires you to have the device attached to the computer to access any files or settings related to that device. I find that annoying. Unfortunately Apple does not care about what I find annoying. I would imagine that is true for the rest of us, as well...

Comment: @SteveChambers nice use of "generally". cough... sync over Wi-Fi... cough

Comment: @shigeya You can just delete those backups from the ~MobileSync/Backups folder, it won't affect anything. Just make sure to check the date of the backup and not to delete any important fresh backup.